# Alterar el flujo de código a la hora de repintar (javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
bucleJuegoVisible = function () {
    //Instrucciones   
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imagen1, canvasX(jugador.x), canvasY(jugador.y), canvasX(jugador.ancho), canvasY(jugador.alto));
    ctx.drawImage(imagen2, canvasX(jugador2.x), canvasY(jugador2.y), canvasX(jugador2.ancho), canvasY(jugador2.alto));
    ctx.drawImage(imagen3, canvasX(jugador3.x), canvasY(jugador3.y), canvasX(jugador3.ancho), canvasY(jugador3.alto));
    play(bucleJuegoVisible);
}
bucleJuegoVisible();
```

Mi idea es que si selecciono imagen2 o imagen1, a la hora de repintar esta se coloque de ultimo en el flujo, es decir, así tal cual como esta, la imagen3 se mostrara siempre por encima de las otras 2, pero si quiero que la imagen2 sea la ultima en repintarse, entonces debería quedar así: imagen1 imagen3 imagen2. (Estoy utilizando canvas por lo que zindex no me funciona), pensé en usar un arreglo, pero no puedo colocar directamente el código de cada una de ellas en el, para eso tendría que colocarlas dentro de comillas, cambiar las posiciones y luego quitarlas, pero siento que existe una solución mejor que esa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Va una idea tratando de interpretar tu pregunta.

## El objetivo

Entiendo que quieres que se pinten en distinto orden la información de jugadores en función de cuál fue el último jugador seleccionado.

## Una posible solución

Colocar la información de jugadores en un arreglo, indicar en el arreglo cuál se fue seleccionando y pintar desde el arreglo.

```js
var datosJugadores=[
   {imagenJugador: imagen1, objetoJugador:jugador },
   {imagenJugador: imagen2, objetoJugador:jugador2 },
   {imagenJugador: imagen3, objetoJugador:jugador3 }
]

bucleJuegoVisible = function () {
    //Instrucciones   
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    datosJugadores.forEach(infoJugador=>{
        var jugador = infoJugador.objetoJugador;
        ctx.drawImage(infoJugador.imagenJugador, canvasX(jugador.x), canvasY(jugador.y), canvasX(jugador.ancho), canvasY(jugador.alto));
    })
    play(bucleJuegoVisible);
}
bucleJuegoVisible();
```

Y para indicar que un jugador fue seleccionado hay que pasarlo al final:

```js
function pasarAlFinal(jugador){
    var posEnArray = datosJugadores.findIndex(infoJugador=>infoJugador.objetoJugador===jugador);
    var elementoAPasar = datosJugadores.splice(datosJugadores,1); // lo quita
    datosJugadores.push(elementoAPasar); // lo pasa al final
}
```

Notas:

1. Si en vez de al final lo necesitas al principio cambia `push` por `unshift`.
2. Aún estando dentro del arreglo puedes seguir usando las variables jugador, jugador2, etc... De todos modos conviene que estén en un arreglo porque eso te permite manejar una cantidad arbitraria de jugadores.
3. Otra mejora podría ser que la imagen esté dentro del objeto jugador así no hay que crear el contenedor `{infoJugador, imagenJugador}` para asociar ambas.